# laravel 8: validation unique multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, rules

I have a situation where I need to validate an identification number in two different tables (companies and units).

The company can register the units it owns, but the system cannot allow the identification code to be duplicated in the tables (companies and units).

A typical validation would look like this:
Store

```
unique:companies,cnpj
```

Update

```
unique:companies,cnpj,{$this->company->id}
```

But I need to add the second table in this condition for validation, so I tried to use it as follows, but validation doesn't happen.

I tried using something like:

Store

```
unique:companies,cnpj|unique:units,cnpj
```

Someone who has been through this type of situation or has knowledge that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change field name to indentification code and try this, hope it helps

```
'field_name' => [ 'unique:companies,cnpj,'.$this->company->id, 'unique:units,cnpj,'.$this->company->id]
```

Comment: I'm stuck in the situation to register the data at the moment
I tried this and the validation doesn't start
'
'cnpj' => [
                'unique:companies,cnpj',
                'unique:units,cnpj'
            ],
'

Comment: and is there any error messages before the validation?

Comment: There was no error message, but I found the problem. One of the records was being recorded with the input mask, so it passed the validation even knowing that the code existed in the database.

But his suggestion helped me a lot, especially in the update part.